# lottery number generator program

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to write a lottery number generator program by using wpf and MVVM structure. I wrote the code below but nothing work. Can you everyone help me?
I have found no mistake and build and debug!

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int duration;
    private string text;
    private DispatcherTimer timer = null;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Duration = 1000;
        this.Text = "00";
        this.StartTimerCommand = new Delegatecommon(this.StartTimer);
        this.StopTimerCommand = new Delegatecommon(this.StopTimer);
    }

    #region Properties

    public int Duration
    {
        get
        {
            return this.duration;
        }
        set
        {
            this.duration = value;
            RaisePropertychange("Duration");
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return this.text;
        }
        set
        {
            this.text = value;
            RaisePropertychange("Text");
        }
    }

    public Delegatecommon StartTimerCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Delegatecommon StopTimerCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion

    public void StartTimer()
    {
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(this.Duration);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerTick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    public void StopTimer()
    {
        if (timer != null)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    private void TimerTick(object send, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random((Int32)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        this.Text = rnd.Next(0, 100).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is not wroking?

Comment: You prepare the timer in the constructor, but you never call the `StartTimer()` method...

Comment: I call in the button. so when i click it it will start the timer.but it is not started at all

Comment: You start with `timer = null` but never call `timer = new DispatcherTimer()`

Comment: I change like what u said but nothing happen

Comment: Maybe be a bit more specific about what is not working. It is not generating the correct lottery numbers?

Answer (score 1):

In your MainViewModel() add this line: **Edited**

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    this.Duration = 1000;
    this.Text = "00";
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = this.Duration;
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerTick);
    this.StartTimerCommand = new Delegatecommon(this.StartTimer);
    this.StopTimerCommand = new Delegatecommon(this.StopTimer);
}

public void StartTimer()
{
    timer.Start();
}

public void StopTimer()
{
    timer.Stop();
}
```

Keeping the rest same as before.

After 30 minutes of scrutiny, I figured out 2 words you're missing...

**&& PropertyChanged != null** in:

```
class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertychange(string propertyname)
    {
        if (propertyname != null && PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }
}
```

Adding that, it worked when I test your code, with my extra modifications that I asked you to make here.

Comment: Try the edited code. Basically, you initialize the timer and set everything at the start, leaving the 2 buttons to simply toggle `timer.Start()` and `timer.Stop()`

Comment: Are you sure you binded the button correctly, could you show some xaml code so we can be sure the problem is not there?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="Randm.View.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Randm.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="RandomNumber" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock FontSize="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Text,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <Button  Width="100" Height="50" Content="Start" FontSize="20" Command="{Binding Path=StartTimerCommand}"></Button>
    <Button  Width="100" Height="50" Content="Stop" FontSize="20" Command="{Binding Path=StopTimerCommand}"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
 class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertychange(string propertyname)
    {
        if(propertyname == null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the textblock line to `<TextBlock FontSize="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>`. You need a twoway mode to change text from code and display it.

Comment: Agree with yu at that point. however, it is still not working.

Comment: Last ditch silly suggestion: remove all the `Path=...`, such as `Binding Path=Text` to `Binding Text` and same for buttons.

Comment: em,Thank you for great help. I think if possibel, seeing the whole program will also help u figure it out.do you want to see it?

Comment: That would be great, as I can help you test it as well.

Comment: How can I send it to u?or you want me to post here?

Comment: Actually I have enough code to test it myself, give me some time I'll get back to you.

Comment: By the way, what is `Delegatecommon`?

Comment: ok i will post it too. It is class that i wrote to make the button work.

Comment: You don't need to add new answers, just edit your question and add the additional code there, I am saying this as I also will need your RaisePropertychange function.

Comment: It is working. Thank you so much. U are such a genius.If there is anything i can help u just tell me.

Comment: Please, in the future, _edit_ your question rather than providing information in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Delegatecommon : ICommand
{
    private Action _execute;
    private Func<bool> _canexecute;

    public Delegatecommon(Action ac) : this(ac, () => true) { }

    public Delegatecommon(Action ac, Func<bool> fu)
    {
        if (ac == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        else if (fu == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        _execute = ac;
        _canexecute = fu;
    }

    event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    public void execute()
    {
        _execute();
    }

    public bool canexecute()
    {
        return _canexecute();
    }
    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canexecute();
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute();
    }
}
```